# Do you need to mock redux dispatch functions in order to test form submit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

Can't test form submit, which uses react-form-hook and after submitting it dispatches and action.

In the last lines doing simply:

```
    fireEvent.submit(screen.getByRole('button'));
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.queryAllByRole('alert')).toHaveLength(0));
    await waitFor(() => expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled());
```

returns Received number of calls:    0

Button is inside form, validation gets triggered when button is pressed via test.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is calling this? ```await waitFor(() => expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled());```

Comment: It is mocked function. Originaly jest.fn() was assigned to variable mockedSubmit.

Comment: Yeah that's my point. How can the mocked function be called when nothing in your code calls the mocked function?

Comment: Do it need to be the same name or smth? In the code its just a submit fn where two dispatches fired - one to update the state with values other to proced to another step in multistep form (next page) so also im trying to test somehow that page change, currently after submit nothing happens just validations pass

Comment: You have to define a mock function ex: ```mockHandleSubmit = jest.fn()``` then you have to call mockHandleSubmit in your test code when the button is pressed Then you can expect mockHandleSubmit to be called 1 time.

Comment: If you want to test the actual redux state then you'll have to use mock dispatching

Comment: Yes Ive done that originaly. But still the form wizzard wont flip other page.

Comment: I have mockedSumit = jest.fn() in the top. Im using it here, just changed into jest.fn() for demonstration

Comment: But why after submit the page doesnt show? In the parent file it dispatches action to redux store and changes the current form step, but cant reproduce that inside tests , just nothing happens after submit

Comment: did you create a mock redux store and dispatch the correct mock actions after?

Comment: I wrapped the component into provider, then passed the original store to it

Comment: Please provide the component and the complete test case, otherwise it's not easy help.